# Django Admin action button per each row in ListView

Tags: javascript, django, django-admin

as in this post from hakibenita https://hakibenita.com/how-to-add-custom-action-buttons-to-django-admin , i would have an action button per each row in admin listview. This button should change the status of the book (simply a char field with choices in models), but i want it to do without opening another page, just a click on the button and the status is changed. The status value is choosen from a select and clicking the action button call a javascript to read the select button, the javascript then call the admin page to change the status. I can't do a form, because each row in listview is already in a form. I don't want to use admin action, because this is an action per single object.

Here is the relevant code:

```
admin.py:
class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin): 
#...

    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super().get_urls()
        custom_urls = [
            path('changestatus/<str:status>/<int:bookid>', self.admin_site.admin_view(self.change_status), name = 'changestatus'),
            ]
        return custom_urls + urls


    def change_status(self, request, bookid=None, status=None):
        if bookid: 
            book = Book.objects.get(pk=bookid)
            if status == 'available':
                book.status = Book.AVAILABLE
            elif status == 'unavailable':
                book.status = Book.UNAVAILABLE
            book.save()
            
            newStatus = book.get_status_display()
            
            self.message_user(request, 'Changed status to "{}"'.format(newStatus), messages.SUCCESS)

        url = reverse(
            'admin:library_book_changelist',
            current_app=self.admin_site.name,
        )
        return HttpResponseRedirect(url)



   def status_button(self, obj):
            return format_html('{}<br />'
                            '<select id="selectstatus">'
                            '<option value="available-{}">Status available</option>'
                            '<option value="unavailable-{}">Status unavailable</option>'
                            '<button onclick="changestatus()">Change Status</button>',
                            obj.get_status_display(),
                            obj.pk,
                            obj.pk,
                            )
    status_button.short_description = 'Status'


#...


myjs.js:
function changestatus(){
    var val=document.getElementById("selectstatus").value;
    var valArr = val.split("-");
    var newstatus = valArr[0];
    var bookid = valArr[1];
    changestatusUrl = "/management/library/book/changestatus/"+newstatus+"/"+bookid; 
//     window.open(changestatusUrl, '_self'); // works, changes status but don't display message
//     window.open(changestatusUrl,); // IT WORKS!! but opens another tab
    window.location.replace(changestatusUrl);  // works, changes status but don't display message
}
```

Many thanks

Comment: Can you not just make the status field and editable field on the dajngo admin list? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_editable

Comment: @LifeByBen it's not a bad idea, but how to control permissions on who could chnage that field?

Comment: Good question - If its fine detail like just being able to update that one field or not I guess you could override the save and in there do a check for permissions something like that?

Comment: checking in save() works, but everybody see the the select dropdown to change... i want people with right permissions only to see the change dropdown